# Running 2560x1080 on second 29'' on Ubuntu 16.04 AMD/ATI HD6790

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi, display-resolution, amd-graphics

I have read many similar threads but nothing seems to solve my issue.

I have purchased a 29'' LG 29UM58-P LED MONITOR which I have connected through HDMI from my AMD Radeon HD6790 graphics card. My old display is a 23'' one that is connected through a D-DVI to HDMI adaptor and displays at the correct resolution (1920x1080). The problem is that I cannot make the 29'' to work at 2560x1080 on Ubuntu 16.04.

There does not seem to be a hardware issue since I also have Windows 10 on the same pc and it recognizes said resolution.

I have tried using xrandr to manually set the resolution (using all possible refresh rates, i.e., 24, 30, 40, 50, 60, 75), but either the screen will become too fuzzy or it will display nothing with an out-of-range message. Example follows:

```
$ cvt 2560 1080 24
# 2560x1080 23.98 Hz (CVT) hsync: 26.33 kHz; pclk: 84.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1080_24.00"   84.25  2560 2632 2880 3200  1080 1083 1093 1098 -hsync +vsync
$ sudo xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_24.00"   84.25  2560 2632 2880 3200  1080 1083 1093 1098 -hsync +vsync
$ sudo xrandr --verbose --addmode HDMI-0 "2560x1080_24.00"
$ sudo xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode "2560x1080_24.00"
```

Before upgrading to 16.04 I tried the same on Ubuntu 14.04 to no avail. I also tried using the fglrx driver but it would cause a problem with the gnome session and lock me in a login loop. After upgrading to 16.04, I also tried using the amd64-microcode firmware, again to no avail.

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:** To simplify the case, I exchanged the connection of the two displays, i.e., the 23'' is now connected directly via the HDMI cable while the 29'' is connected via the HDMI cable on a DL-DVI to HDMI adaptor.

2560x1080 is again recognized immediately and works on Windows; on Ubuntu, I can now see it on the resolutions list on the Displays panel, however when I select it I get a no-signal message on my 29'' monitor and a blank screen (until i revert back to the stretched 1920x1080).

Comment: How exactly are you connecting the monitor under Windows to get the resolution? Are you certain it's the full resolution and not just scaled? https://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/6000/6790 indicates that HDMI only supports 1920x1200, and for larger you need to use DisplayPort 1.2 or Dual-Link DVI.

Comment: With the exact same way, i.e., through HDMI. I know about the max res and was planning to use the Dual-Link DVI to HDMI adaptor for that purpose since the monitor only accepts HDMI input, however it apparently just works directly (at least in the Windows case)!

Comment: Yes, it is definetely not scaled or stretched (just confirmed it one more time).

Comment: Are both HDMI cables exactly the same? Are they 1.4 or 2.0 compatible? Have you verified the timings that you added to xrandr with what is specified in the Windows driver's .inf file?

Comment: How should I do that? In the driver's .inf there is the following entry

`[ULTRAWIDE_DVI.AddReg]
HKR,"MODES\2560,1080",Mode1,,"30.0-90.0,56.0-75.0,+,+"
HKR,,PreferredMode,,"2560,1080,60"
HKR,,ICMprofile,0,"ULTRAWIDE.ICM"`

while `cvt 2560 1080` outputs

`# 2560x1080 59.98 Hz (CVT) hsync: 67.17 kHz; pclk: 230.00 MHz
Modeline "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync`

Is this what you're refering to?

Comment: Well, in your question it looks like you're trying to use 24 Hz for some reason. Have you tried 30 Hz or 60 Hz instead?

Comment: As I mention in the question, I tried using a range of Hz ( i.e., 24, 30, 40, 50, 60, and 75)

Comment: OK. I think it might be a bug in the driver or xrandr perhaps. I've also been unable to get my 4K monitor to work properly at 60 Hz on both AMD and Intel video.